# Evaluation of $~\Delta\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}y^{2k}\right\}$

Tags: derivatives, summation, binomial-coefficients, partial-derivative, binomial-theorem

$$\Delta f:={\partial^2 f\over\partial x^2}+{\partial^2 f\over\partial y^2}\tag{1}$$

$$f(x,y):= \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}y^{2k}}_{\text{I assume}~(x,y)\neq(0,0)}  \tag{2}$$

$$\begin{align}
\Delta f&= \underbrace{\Delta\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}y^{2k}\right\}}_{\text{What I want to evaluate.} }  \\&= {\partial\over\partial x} \left({\partial\over\partial x} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}y^{2k}\right) \right) +{\partial\over\partial y} \left({\partial\over\partial y} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}y^{2k}\right) \right)\\&=
{\partial  \over\partial x} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}y^{2k} {\partial  \over\partial x} x^{40-2k}   \right)+{\partial  \over\partial y} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}  {\partial  \over\partial y}   y^{2k}\right)
\\&=
{\partial  \over\partial x} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}y^{2k} (40-2k) x^{39-2k}   \right)+{\partial  \over\partial y} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}  (2k)  y^{2k-1}\right)
\\&=
 \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}y^{2k} (40-2k) {\partial  \over\partial x}x^{39-2k}   +\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}  (2k){\partial  \over\partial y}  y^{2k-1}
 \\&=
 \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}y^{2k} (40-2k)(39-2k)x^{38-2k}   +\sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k}\binom{40}{2k}x^{40-2k}  (2k)(2k-1)  y^{2k-2}
 \\&=
 \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k} \binom{40}{2k}\left\{ y^{2k} (40-2k)(39-2k)x^{38-2k}   +x^{40-2k}  (2k)(2k-1)  y^{2k-2} \right\} 
  \\&=
 \sum_{k=0}^{20}(-1)^{k} \binom{40}{2k}x^{38-2k}y^{2k-2}\left\{ y^{2} (40-2k)(39-2k)   +x^{2}  (2k)(2k-1) \right\} \\&=
 \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{20}2(-1)^{k} \binom{40}{2k}x^{38-2k}y^{2k-2}\left\{  (20-k)(39-2k)y^{2}   +  (k)(2k-1)x^2 \right\} }_{\text{Seems I can't simplify the terms moreover} } 
\end{align}$$

The original problem is from the $3$rd year transfer exam of math major in the university. I am confused by the person who made this problem.

**PostScript**

Owing to MH.Lee, I've got many progress from the initial my post's content.

And thought that I should give up evaluating the equation temporarily since
achille hui showed me the quite genius equation that seems really difficult for me so far.

Comment: Why? $\partial/\partial x_i$ is $\mathbb R$-linear map!

Comment: Don't feel constrained to keep things grouped the way they are inside the summation.  Instead, regroup your terms so that all like terms are combined.  It may help if you use $\ldots$ notation instead of summation notation and write out multiple terms to see the pattern of how things can combine.

Comment: Hint: $f(x,y) = \frac12\left((x+iy)^{40}+(x-iy)^{40}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mean question! The answer is zero.

Our first observation is that the sum looks a lot like a binomial expansion; e.g. the expansion of $(x + y)^{40}$ would be $\sum_k {40 \choose k} x^{n-k} y^k$. This sum is similar but contains only even terms; you may or may not know that the secret to isolating the even terms of a polynomial $f(x)$ is to take $\frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$. Applying that observation to $(x + y)^{40}$ gives

$$\frac{(x + y)^{40} + (x - y)^{40}}{2} = \sum_k {40 \choose 2k} x^{n-2k} y^{2k}.$$

This is still not the desired expression because there is that extra factor of $(-1)^k$. But by writing $-1 = i^2$ and hence $(-1)^k = i^{2k}$ we can absorb this into $y$, producing

$$\frac{(x + iy)^{40} + (x - iy)^{40}}{2} = \sum_k (-1)^k {40 \choose 2k} x^{n-2k} y^{2k}.$$

This is much better! Now we want to apply the Laplacian to this expression. It's a straightforward computation from here, just a few applications of the power rule, but it turns out we can do even better.

At this point you might remember a fact from your complex analysis class: a function satisfying $\Delta f = 0$ is called a [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function), and the real or complex part of any [holomorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) is harmonic. And for $x, y$ real the above expression is the real part of the holomorphic function $z^{40}$. So its Laplacian is zero.

More explicitly, we introduce the change of variables $z = x + iy, \bar{z} = x - iy$, so that the expression is $\frac{z^{40} + \bar{z}^{40}}{2}$. This change of variables can be paired with a corresponding change of variables on differential operators, the [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Formal_definition)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}}{2}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}}{2}.$$

These have been constructed to satisfy the identities $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} z = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} z = 1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \bar{z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} z = 0$. It's a pleasant fact that for a function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) say exactly that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$, and it's another pleasant fact that the $2$-dimensional Laplacian factors as

$$\Delta = 4 \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}.$$

This immediately implies that $\Delta f = 0$ for $f$ any polynomial in $z$ or any polynomial in $\bar{z}$ (since the above identities give $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} z^n = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \bar{z}^n = 0$ by the product rule), and more generally for any function which is either holomorphic or anti-holomorphic (meaning that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$). The desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Aaron's hint is also a good hint; you didn't get any further simplifications because you didn't collect like terms. You can patiently collect like terms and that will also work but why do that when the binomial coefficients are staring you right in the face?